# Which ESRI defined geographic transformation do I need to use to convert my " NAD83 Northern Virginia" data into WGS 1984 Web Mercator?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

My title pretty much tells it all..

I have a number of datasets in which I want to batch project from NAD83 Northern Virginia Datum into the correct Web Mercator projection..

When I do a straight re-projection I get an error message.. this tells me that I need to use a transformation of some kind.. I think..

So, here in lies my problem.. as there is not a web mercator projection transformation listed in the geographic transformation I was thinking I would just use a generic one like...

NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_2 *(there are 8 different ones)*
WGS_1984_Major_Auxillary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984

But I am not sure that is correct.. Which is the correct "geographic transformation"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The esri doc on [choosing an appropriate transformation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003r00000010000000.htm) is probably what you want. Specifically:

> NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5: Transformation
>   parameters calculated by the U.S.
>   National Geodetic Survey (NGS) using
>   CORS stations, and ties WGS 1984 to
>   ITRF96. Accuracy according to EPSG is
>   +/- 1 meter.

Answer (score 1):

see [Does Re-Projecting ShapeFile only update content of *.prj file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/does-re-projecting-an-esri-shapefile-only-update-the-content-of-the-prj-file/2424#2424) for a picture which makes sense of all those words on the help page in 2 seconds.