# Projection transformations from EPSG 6347 to EPSG 4326

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I am quite new to GIS and I have a question regarding projection transformations.

I am using GeoPandas to read a map in [EPSG 6347](https://epsg.io/6347) and I use the method `to_crs` to convert it to [EPSG 4326](https://epsg.io/4326), as documented [here](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/projections.html).

As far as I understand, the ellipsoid and the datum are entirely specified in the EPSG:

| EPSG | CRS | Datum | Ellipsoid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6347 | NAD83 | 2011 | GRS80 |
| 4326 | WSG84 | 1984 | WSG64 |

and therefore, I thought that there would only be one possible transformation.

The first answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/transforming-gcs-north-american-1983-to-gcs-wgs-1984-using-arcgis-desktop) indicates that there are multiple transformations from NAD83 to WSG84. This is also explained in [this link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929). Those transformations are named: NAD_1983_To_WSG_1984_1,..., NAD_1983_To_WSG_1984_8.

Which of those 8 transformations is used by GeoPandas when it converts from EPSG:6347 to EPSG:4326?

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. Otherwise it will be harder to answer and later on to find the correct answer for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proj version 8.1.1 finds only one conversion between those two codes:

```
projinfo -s epsg:6347 -t epsg:4326 --spatial-test intersects
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of UTM zone 18N + Ballpark geographic offset from NAD83(2011) to WGS 84, unknown accuracy, World, has ballpark transformation

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of UTM zone 18N + Ballpark geographic offset from NAD83(2011) to WGS 84",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 18N",
            BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",
                DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",6318]],
            CONVERSION["UTM zone 18N",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6347]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of UTM zone 18N",
            METHOD["Inverse of Transverse Mercator",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",9807]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-75,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",16018]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["Ballpark geographic offset from NAD83(2011) to WGS 84",
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",
                    DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",
                        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",6318]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4326]]],
            METHOD["Geographic2D offsets",
                ID["EPSG",9619]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8601]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8602]]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I think you made a typo: you wrote `epsg:3647` instead of `epsg:6347`. I tried with the correct epsg and it also gave me only one conversion. The outcome of the command starts with `unknown id`, is it the transformation id that is missing?

Comment: Thanks, corrected the typo and projinfo output. I am not sure what the unknown_id means. I tried projinfo with some other codes and sometimes there was a name in the result, sometimes unknown_id. Perhaps the names are somewhere in the EPSG database https://epsg.org/search/by-name.

Comment: Ok, I see. Can we conclude that GeoPandas can only do the right transformation (as there is only one available) and the that 8 transformations `NAD_1983_To_WSG_1984_1`,...,`NAD_1983_To_WSG_1984_8` are all possible transformations between NAD83 and WSG84 when the datum and / or ellipsoid is not specified? I tried to find the `WKID` displayed in [this link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929) in the output of the `projinfo`command, hoping to match the transformation done by GeoPandas, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I believe that the other transformations are not valid within the valid area of EPSG:6347 even with the  "intersects" test. I do not know enough about GeoPandas to say that it cannot do anything else.